# XPages partial refresh with contidion

Tags: xpages

I would like to make partial refresh according to a field's value.
I mean If the Value equals to "1" onChange of a field should make a partial refresh otherwise there should be no update. is that possible?

```
<xp:inputText id="fields" value="#{sessionScope.fields[index]}">
<xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId='#{javascript:var c1 = "divContentPage";
    var c2 = "";
    if (document1.getItemValueString("FieldName")=="1")
        return c1;
    else
        return c2;}'>
 <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:try
    {
        reloadValues();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        print(e.toString())
    }}]]></xp:this.action>
                                                    </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:inputText>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPages disable eventHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524155/xpages-disable-eventhandler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. On the event use client-side JavaScript for the condition, returning `true` or `false`. If the client-side JavaScript returns false, the partial refresh (and thus SSJS / Java) will not trigger. If it returns true, the partial refresh (and thus SSJS / Java) will trigger.